# Using X-Editable with Django - not returning JSON

Tags: jquery, json, django, x-editable

I've read through every answer I could find and nothing seems click with me so I can get my project working. I have a Django site that I would like to use X-editable ( similar to Jquery I believe ) but can't figure out how to send my data in JSON, but it gets sent in AJAX. I am sure it's something simple, but I can't find my error. My code is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en"> </html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script   src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <p></p>

        <div class="container">
       <table class="table table-hover table-responsive"{% if table.attrs %}     {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
        <tr>
          <th>Project</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Percent on Project</th>
          <th>Total Utilization</th>
          <th>Start</th>
          <th>End</th>
        </tr>
      {% for detail in utilization %}
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">{{ detail.proj }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-2"> {{ detail.employee.last_name }} </td>
            <td class="col-md-2"><a href="#" id="projectAllocation" data-name="percent_allocated" data-params="{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'}" class="editable" data-url="/employee_post" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ detail.id }}" title="Project Name">{{ detail.percent_allocated }}</a></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"> {{ detail.total_utilization }} </td>
        <td class="col-md-1"> {{ detail.week_start }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"> {{ detail.target_complete }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn save-btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>

    <script charset="utf-8">
  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
</script>

<script charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.editable').editable();
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: {'data': JSON.stringify(document.getElementById(detail))},
     cookie: 'csrftoken',
      xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
}});





</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is in setting the `name` attribute incorrectly. I feel it should be `<a href="#" name="percent_allocated"` rather than `<a href="#" name="{{ detail.percent_allocated }}"`. Or if you are dynamically setting the name, then you should change `JSON.stringify(document.getElementById(percent_allocated))}` to `JSON.stringify(document.getElementById({{detail.percent_allocated}}))}`.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Thank you, but I tired that perviously using the {{dynamicDjangoVar}} , but it is not within the scope of the js. I will attempt to reload the template variable and then use it within the JS.. just don't know if that works. Thanks again.

Comment: You should also add quotes around the variable like this - `JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("{{detail.percent_allo‌​cated}}"))`

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil thanks again. The format of my Django Queryset is odd and doesn't play well with js because it's not a simple list. That said, I have found a way to reformat the array, but am having issues

Comment: Still having issues. The data is being sent back to my server, but it's in AJAX and I want JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: Dave, I would need a lot more info to help you out. But I would definitely recommend trying all the steps manually, i.e. getting queryset result from django, then checking if JSON.stringify works correctly on that, etc. This way you can hopefully drill down to the exact cause. Good luck!